# Cypress error after update from Angular 12 to 13

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, frontend, cypress

I have an Angular project with three subproject inside. I am using ng-packagr.

After updating to Angular 13, The Cypress tests doesn't run because I get this error

"Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module '@angular/common/http'"

I read it is failing because something change in Webpack from 4 to 5 but I don't know how I can fix it.

I just followed the step to upgrade Angular from 12 to 13

My dependencies

```
{
  ................................,
  ................................,
  "dependencies": {
    "@amplitude/analytics-browser": "^1.9.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.10",
    "@angular/animations": "~13.3.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.3.10",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.12",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "13.3.12",
    "@angular/core": "~13.3.12",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.12",
    "@angular/localize": "~13.3.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.12",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.12",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.7.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^10.0.3",
    "angular-resize-element": "^1.2.0",
    "atob": "^2.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "ng-click-outside": "^6.0.0",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.1",
    "ngx-timeago": "^1.0.4",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.1.0",
    "ngx-virtual-scroller": "^4.0.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "13.5.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~13.3.12",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.11",
    "@types/cucumber": "^6.0.1",
    "@types/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/jasmine-expect": "^3.8.1",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.28.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.28.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "concurrently": "^6.3.0",
    "cucumber": "^6.0.5",
    "cucumber-html-reporter": "^5.2.0",
    "cypress": "^12.0.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.0.0",
    "cypress-iframe": "^1.0.1",
    "cypress-wait-until": "^1.7.1",
    "del": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-expect": "^5.0.0",
    "json-server": "^0.17.1",
    "karma": "^6.3.8",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter": "^0.0.23",
    "lcov-result-merger": "^3.1.0",
    "mocha": "^9.1.3",
    "mochawesome": "^7.0.1",
    "mochawesome-merge": "^4.2.0",
    "mochawesome-report-generator": "^6.2.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^13.3.1",
    "prettier": "2.0.5",
    "pretty-quick": "^2.0.1",
    "sonar-scanner": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "tslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.3.0",
    "wait-on": "^6.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: And what version of cypress are you running?

Comment: Do you try this? https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/issues/537#issuecomment-1454181301

Please pose your package.json

Comment: I just updated my post @E.Maggini

Comment: Looks like you DO have cucumber...did you try this suggested fix? https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/issues/537#issuecomment-1454181301